# ActiveRecord create without_protection - wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't work out what's wrong with this create statement on my User model:

```
User.create({first_name: "Alan",....}, :without_protection => true)
```

Gives me the stack trace:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
from /Users/alanheppenstall/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:32:in `create'
from (irb):56
from /Users/alanheppenstall/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /Users/alanheppenstall/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/alanheppenstall/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

My syntax matches: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class/

I'm using devise with this model - could that be an issue? I couldn't find anywhere where they override initialize().

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, they removed options in Rails 4 and this hasn't been updated in places like APIdock (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class/)

You can see the difference between current and 3.2:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb

and

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb

Comment: Great. So how do I use it now?

Comment: Since the protection has moved to strong_params in controllers I think that you can assign any values without passing this flag. When you try to create a record without passing the option do you see an error?

Comment: I got this working now. I was struggling, as it turned out, with some database defaults.

Answer (score 1):

It's removed in rails 4

Now you can just create without setting the flag

```
User.create({id: 101, first_name: "Alan",....})
```

Rails will create new record with **`id = 101`** without the flag

But you will get an error if any record with id **`101`** already exist

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"