# How to create a model without controller considering rails4 strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Cannot find anywhere the accepted way to create a model without going through controller considering that attr_accissible is no longer supported.

Is the below approach correct?

in my old code:

```
ModelName.create(course_id:680, user_id:25)
```

(raises mass_assignment error now that I have removed attr_accessible)

new code:

```
model = ModelName.new.tap do |m| 
  m.course_id = 680
  m.user_id = 25
end
model.save!
```

(works but looks hacky)

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864818/activerecord-create-without-protection-wrong-number-of-arguments-2-for-1), the below will not work because without_protection option is removed in Rails4

```
ModelName.create({course_id: 680, user_id: User.first.id}, without_protection: true)
```

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510977/upgrading-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-and-params?lq=1) I've read about strong parameters 'Use outside of Controllers' - [link](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) but even if I do the following from my console:

```
raw_params = {course_id: Course.last.id, user_id: User.first.id}
parameters = ActionController::Parameters.new(raw_params)
ModelName.create(parameters.permit(:course_id, :user_id))
```

I get error

```
WARN -- : WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for ModelName: course_id, user_id
```

Comment: If mass-assignment of attributes is optional for your model you can avoid such situation by changing this line `config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict` to `config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :logger` in your environments/development.rb file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510977/upgrading-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-and-params?lq=1) more carefully and found my answer

I had to add

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

to my environments (development/test/production.rb), maybe because I still have the protected_attributes gem installed.

so now I can happily use

```
ModelName.create(course_id:680, user_id:25)
```

afterall.

I realise this question/answer is somewhat of a repeat of the aforementioned question - but I did find that question a bit tricky to understand, so I won't take this question down unless asked.